# unclosed regular expression

Tags: regex, jshint, reactjs

I have the following code:

```
render() {  
         /* jshint laxbreak: true */  
         var buttonClasses = classSet({  
              'Button' : true,  
        }),  
        buttonContainerClasses = classSet({  
          'u-textRight': !this.props.fullscreen  
        }),  
        allowedTypes = /^(submit|button)$/i,  
        type = allowedTypes.test(this.props.type)  
             ? this.props.type  
             : 'button';  

    return (  
      <div className={buttonContainerClasses}>  
        <input  
          type = {type}  
          value = {this.props.label}  
        />  
      </div>  
   );  
}
```

and JSHint is giving me the following error:

```
Unclosed regular expression
```

on the line that closes the input tag (second last line).
I'm currently trying to upgrade to React 0.12.2, and im fixing up all the errors. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I always had the impression that JSHint could only validate JavaScript… instead of… HTML.

Comment: That's HTML, not Javascript. Use an HTML validator, not JSHint.

Comment: @Barmar But even then I’m pretty sure the `{}` syntax is not gonna work with an HTML5 validator. But maybe this helps: as far as this code snippet is concerned and the `{}` syntax is supposed to be there, **congratulations:** you have valid syntax.

Comment: Right. This looks like he's using some kind of template framework. If you want to validate the HTML, you have to do it with the result after replacing the template keywords.

Comment: Sorry i should have clarified, this is inside my render function, and the part that JSHint is complaining about is the `return ( )` part of the render function (part of which i have pasted above). the render function itself is in JS. when i run gulp lint/build when React is set to an older version, everything runs fine without any errors, so i'm not sure why React 0.12 is complaining about it :( @Barmar @Xufox

Comment: Please post the actual Javascript code. It's hard to tell what's going on with just the excerpt, which has no JS code. It looks like JSHint is seeing the `/>` and thinks that's the beginning of a RegExp literal.

Comment: @Barmar i've edited the question with the full code (some stripped out, i think i'd get in trouble if i posted the full thing :/ )

Comment: That's not valid Javascript. Reactjs uses a preprocessor that lets you put HTML directly into JS statements, but JSHint doesn't understand it.

Comment: I just took a look at the React web site. What you've got there is called **JSX**. If you want to use JSHint, you need to convert to the compiled syntax. See https://facebook.github.io/react/ and click on the "Compiled JS" tabs to see the difference.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense as to why it works in react 0.11, and not react 0.12. hmmm. i'll keep digging around. Thank you!

Comment: do you HAVE to use the ugly self-closing XML-like syntax `<input/>` in JSX? or can you use the good old HTML5-like syntax `<input>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've worked it out! So in React 0.12, the pragma can be removed, however lint won't work without it, hence the error popping up. Thank you to everyone who helped out!

Comment: What does that mean "the pragma can be removed", and how do I do so ?

Answer (score 0):

The extension runs jshint on the complete jsx file, and jshint doesn't support jsx syntax and its features.
I simply turned off the JShint using -> (Code-> Preferences-> Settings->  User extensions-> JSHint configuration-> JSHint:Enable tick box-> Off)

One solution would be manually turning off jshint around the functions returning HTML using `/* jshint ignore: start */` and `/* jshint ignore: end */`.

This answer can also be read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70835790/18018668 for a similar question.