# How do I fix linting error on jsx closing tags : "unclosed regular expression"?

Tags: reactjs, sublimetext3, jsx, eslint, sublimelinter

*(PS none of these SO questions (with inaccurate titles) solved, or addressed, this issue: [React Linting: Unclosed Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44934444/react-linting-unclosed-regular-expression), [unclosed regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403094/unclosed-regular-expression), [React JSX error : Unclosed regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44861564/react-jsx-error-unclosed-regular-expression))*

How do I fix linting error on jsx closing tags : "unclosed regular expression" ?

For example, this code snippet runs fine, but causes a SublimeLinter Error:

```
class Users extends React.Component {
  render() {

    var friends = this.props.list.filter(function(user){
        return user.friend === true;
    });
    var nonFriends = this.props.list.filter(function(user){
        return !user.friend;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Friends</h1>
        <ul>
          ...
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The linter balks at the `</h1>` closing JSX tag, thinking it's the start of a regular expression.
`1-2 of 2 errors: Unclosed regular expression; Unrecoverable syntax error. (42% scanned), 2 lines, 25 characters selected`

Relevant packages I have installed in Sublime Text3:
*SublimeLinter, SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint, JSHint, Babel*

**edit**:
I just added the package "JSX", but that didn't help.
I've searched for the "sublimeLinter-jsxhint" package, but cannot find it.

Comment: Are you using jsx as the file extension? I wonder if Sublime doesn't understand that you actually have JSX on the page instead of plain JS.

Answer (score 2):

The extension runs jshint on the complete jsx file, and jshint doesn't support jsx syntax and its features.
I simply turned off the JShint using -> (Code-> Preferences-> Settings->  User extensions-> JSHint configuration-> JSHint:Enable tick box-> Off)

One solution would be manually turning off jshint around the functions returning HTML using `/* jshint ignore: start */` and `/* jshint ignore: end */`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SublimeLinter-contrib-eslint AND JSHint, you are probably having problems with them conflicting. I'd remove JSHint from Sublime, unless you use it in your build pipeline, then remove the eslint package instead.